# How to bulk extract AWS Cloudwatch logs with the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We want to get extract cloud watch logs over the past year, however the web interface limits to 1000 results per query.

The plan is to use the AWS CLI to extract user logs over the past year.
The CLI first needs the query started and then getting the result of the query. Below is a simplified version of the query used.

```
$query = aws logs start-query --profile test --log-group-name ecs-logs 
        --start-time 1646724254 --end-time  1651991054 
        --query-string "fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log | sort @timestamp desc"
$result =  aws logs get-query-results --profile prod --query-id $query --output json
```

The issue is that each result query takes about half a second making it too slow to get 1000s of logs out. I'm thinking to parallelize the $results query, but does AWS support another way?

Comment: how about export them to S3 and download?

Comment: can I export a query result, or do you mean export all logs and then search from there?

Comment: There are a few ways to search the data in the logs. 1. Use CloudWatch Logs insights or 2. you could store them in S3, use Glue crawler to create the tables from the data and then use Athena to query (there will be some cost associated).